# How can I split a list of lists of tuples if I don't have a column formed by only one element in the column selected?

Tags: python

The code below was tailored for data like this:

```
[['slashdot', 'USA', 'yes', 18, 'None'],
 ['google', 'France', 'yes', 23, 'Premium'],
 ['digg', 'USA', 'yes', 24, 'Basic'],
 ...
]
```

Instead, my data looks like this:

```
[[(0,'y'), (0,'n'), (1,'n'), (2,'y'), (3,'y')],
 [(0,'y'), (0,'y'), (1,'y'), (2,'y'), (3,'n')], ...]
```

here's the code

```
def divideset(rows,column,value):
   # Make a function that tells us if a row is in the first group (true) or the second group (false)
   split_function=None
   if isinstance(value,int) or isinstance(value,float): # check if the value is a number i.e int or float
      split_function=lambda row:row[column]>=value
   else:
      split_function=lambda row:row[column]==value

   # Divide the rows into two sets and return them
   set1=[row for row in rows if split_function(row)]
   set2=[row for row in rows if not split_function(row)]
   return (set1,set2)
```

The result of the function applied on the first data is

```
([['slashdot', 'USA', 'yes', 18, 'None'],
  ['google', 'France', 'yes', 23, 'Premium'],
  ['digg', 'USA', 'yes', 24, 'Basic'],
  ['kiwitobes', 'France', 'yes', 23, 'Basic'],
  ['slashdot', 'France', 'yes', 19, 'None'],
  ['digg', 'New Zealand', 'yes', 12, 'Basic'],
  ['google', 'UK', 'yes', 18, 'Basic'],
  ['kiwitobes', 'France', 'yes', 19, 'Basic']],
 [['google', 'UK', 'no', 21, 'Premium'],
  ['(direct)', 'New Zealand', 'no', 12, 'None'],
  ['(direct)', 'UK', 'no', 21, 'Basic'],
  ['google', 'USA', 'no', 24, 'Premium'],
  ['digg', 'USA', 'no', 18, 'None'],
  ['google', 'UK', 'no', 18, 'None'],
  ['kiwitobes', 'UK', 'no', 19, 'None'],
  ['slashdot', 'UK', 'no', 21, 'None']])
```

If I apply it to my code, I have one empty set and the other with all the data.

Comment: It could be easier to help you if you show us 1. how the function was invoked on the original data, 2. how you have invoked it on _your_ data and 3. on which criterium you want to split your data — If you decide to integrate your question with these important details, please don't provide them as a comment but rather edit the body of your answer.  While we are at it, may I mention that imho the function that you're trying to reuse is not well designed and it is also inefficient, as it scans all the data twice?

Comment: Are you by any chance forgetting to take into account that the code you provided will (as it is now) check for equality of the tuples that are in your list of lists? And unless you passed a tuple to the function call, the condition will always return False, which is why set2 will be a copy of your inputdata and set1 will be empty. Depending on what you want to filter on, you might just need to add one more level of indexing to your lambdas, e.g. `row[column][tuple_index]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following code we first redefine `dividedata` so that it is a bit more flexible (and efficient) and later we test our new implementation on the two different types of data that you showed us — with respect to the criterium to use with your data I had to improvise...

The new `dividedata` has no more fixed tests that are chosen according to the type of the value passed to the function, but leverages Python's ability to threat functions as data, `test` must be a function that you define elsewhere in you code or define on the fly, in the call to `dividedata`, using the `lambda` syntax.

```
from __future__ import print_function

def dividedata(data, col_num, test=None):
    "Doc string placeholder"

    # if no test function was passed, return (quite arbitrarily)
    # a shallow copy of the original list and an empty list
    if test==None: return data[:], []

    set0, set1 = [], []
    for row in data:
        if test(row[col_num]):
            set0.append(row)
        else:
            set1.append(row)

    return set0, set1

my_data = [[(0, 'y'), (0, 'n'), (1, 'n'), (2, 'y'), (3, 'y')],
           [(0, 'y'), (0, 'y'), (1, 'y'), (2, 'y'), (3, 'n')]]

their_data = [['slashdot', 'USA', 'yes', 18, 'None'],
              ['google', 'France', 'yes', 23, 'Premium'],
              ['digg', 'USA', 'yes', 24, 'Basic'],
              ['kiwitobes', 'France', 'yes', 23, 'Basic'],
              ['slashdot', 'France', 'yes', 19, 'None'],
              ['digg', 'New Zealand', 'yes', 12, 'Basic'],
              ['google', 'UK', 'yes', 18, 'Basic'],
              ['kiwitobes', 'France', 'yes', 19, 'Basic'],
              ['google', 'UK', 'no', 21, 'Premium'],
              ['(direct)', 'New Zealand', 'no', 12, 'None'],
              ['(direct)', 'UK', 'no', 21, 'Basic'],
              ['google', 'USA', 'no', 24, 'Premium'],
              ['digg', 'USA', 'no', 18, 'None'],
              ['google', 'UK', 'no', 18, 'None'],
              ['kiwitobes', 'UK', 'no', 19, 'None'],
              ['slashdot', 'UK', 'no', 21, 'None']]

c2y, c2n = dividedata(their_data, 2, lambda answer: answer=='yes')
c1y, c1n = dividedata(my_data, 1, lambda tup: tup[1]=='y')

print(c2y, c2n, sep='\n')
print(c1y, c1n, sep='\n')
```

Comment: I will try this in hours

Comment: Yes it seems more efficient according to time required.